# Why is the Adafruit splashscreen logo not displayed properly?

Tags: adafruit, oled

I'm working with a 128x64 Oled display. I have just installed the Adafruit library and I'm running some sample codes. I have not modified the sample code in anyway yet just testing if the oled display is working but I've noticed that the splashscreen logo only shows the top half of the image.

How can I fix this?

[image: Splashscreen]

Comment: What sample code are you running? That looks like the sample code supposes a different display height

Comment: I'm running the ssd1306_128x64_i2c

Comment: Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: https://codebender.cc/example/Adafruit_SSD1306/ssd1306_128x64_i2c#ssd1306_128x64_i2c.ino

Comment: I added #define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 64 before line #53 to remove the compilation error

Comment: It looks like you're displaying only 50% of the lines with a blank between each one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I'm unable to test this now, but here goes:</s>
Turns out I *did* have the ability to test it (found an extra display module) and this does indeed explain the problem. The only other change I needed to make to your code in order to replicate the problem was change the display's I2C address to `0x3C`. Adafruit GFX Library v1.10.13 and Adafruit SSD1306 version v2.5.1.

---

From comments on the question:

> I added `#define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 64` before line #53 to remove the
> compilation error

Yeah, you can't do that. Under the old method of defining the screen dimensions, you are intended to modify the [header](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/4759c417580bfeba3803fb31f28b9285cfa3419e/Adafruit_SSD1306.h#L27) itself:

```cpp
// ONE of the following three lines must be #defined:
//#define SSD1306_128_64 ///< DEPRECTAED: old way to specify 128x64 screen
#define SSD1306_128_32 ///< DEPRECATED: old way to specify 128x32 screen
//#define SSD1306_96_16  ///< DEPRECATED: old way to specify 96x16 screen
// This establishes the screen dimensions in old Adafruit_SSD1306 sketches
// (NEW CODE SHOULD IGNORE THIS, USE THE CONSTRUCTORS THAT ACCEPT WIDTH
// AND HEIGHT ARGUMENTS).
```

You can see by default it is using a screen with dimensions 128x32. [Later in the header](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/4759c417580bfeba3803fb31f28b9285cfa3419e/Adafruit_SSD1306.h#L116) this is used to set `SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT` to `32` in the header.

```cpp
#if defined SSD1306_128_32
#define SSD1306_LCDWIDTH 128 ///< DEPRECATED: width w/SSD1306_128_32 defined
#define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 32 ///< DEPRECATED: height w/SSD1306_128_32 defined
#endif
```

What you have done in your code is **re**define `SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT` to `64` from the point where you issued the `#define` downward, which *only affects the code compiled in your sketch*.

Meanwhile, [over in Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/4759c417580bfeba3803fb31f28b9285cfa3419e/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp#L330), `SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT` is *still* `32`, because this file is compiled independently of your .ino and is unaware of your own re`#define`.  In other words, part of the code you've put into your Arduino thinks it has 32 lines and part of it thinks it has 64 lines.

---

So, the solution would be get rid of the `#define` that you inserted into the sketch and to modify header to read:

```cpp
#define SSD1306_128_64 ///< DEPRECTAED: old way to specify 128x64 screen
//#define SSD1306_128_32 ///< DEPRECATED: old way to specify 128x32 screen
//#define SSD1306_96_16  ///< DEPRECATED: old way to specify 96x16 screen
```

Or to use the new method of supplying the dimensions by way of the constructor as is done in [newer examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/f8b3aeb/examples/ssd1306_128x64_i2c/ssd1306_128x64_i2c.ino#L26):

```cpp
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
/// ...
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
```

The Adafruit SSD1306 version v2.5.1's ssd1306_128x64_i2c.ino example that uses this newer method of passing screen dimensions into the `Adafruit_SSD1306` constructor and compiled and ran without modification in testing here.

Comment: I have edited the header file and it fixes the problem, thank you. One question though, do I need to use 0x3D as the address for the oled? I used 0x3C because it does not turn on when I use 0x3D. I just want to know why that happened

Comment: In short, if it's working you have chosen the correct address. The SSD1306 controller chip has a pile of different pins and transfer modes. In I2C mode one of those pins can be used to configure to chip to respond to either 0x3C or 0x3D, such that two of those displays could coexist on the same I2C bus with no other changes. For your display, the choice of I2C interface and 0x3C address has been made for you by the PCB design.  I believe the 0x3C/0x3D hard configuration tends to follow the x32/x64 display type, but that nothing guarantees that.